# char pointers and the IF statement

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

I have a char pointer returned from a function, and i want to double check its value using the IF statement how should i implement this one in C.

substring function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770902/to-find-the-substring-in-a-given-text-c-programm)

I want it something like this

```
if (substring("xxxNameYYY",0,3)=="xxx"){
     //do this
} else {
     //do that
}
```

the above if statement always go to "do that" part.

thanks

Comment: THANK YOU everyone, everyones answer was helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot compare string like that in C, you have to use `strcmp(str1, str2) == 0` to check if they are equal.

In your case:

```
char * substr = substring("xxxNameYYY",0,3);
if (strcmp(substr, "xxx") == 0) {
    /* TODO */
}
else {
    /* TODO */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a pointer, doing == is comparing the value of the pointer, not the string its pointing to.  So the pointer returned will never equal the pointer pointing to "xxx".  You need to compare the characters in the strings using strcmp or some variation of it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!strncmp("xxxNameYYY", "xxx", 3))
```

this should work, the reason that that is failing is because in C string constants are allocated in the .data section because their size is known at compile time. What you end up comparing is address of `substring("xxxNameYYY", 0, 3)` with the address of "xxx" which are never going to be equal.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `substring` function returns a C string (which is a pointer to `char` values) and you compare that to another C string - so you're effectively comparing two pointer addresses. These two pointers will never be the same, hence you get into the else branch.

The best fix for this is to not use the `substring` function in the first place; the function allocates memory internally, and it's your responsibility to release the memory (using `free`). This is quite error-prone.

Instead, you can use the [`strncmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) function to do the comparison. I would wrap that in a `startsWith` function, like this:

```
/* Yields true if s starts with t */
bool startsWith( const char *s, const char *t )
{
  return strncmp( s, t, strlen( t ) ) == 0;
}
```

You could then simplify your code to

```
if (startsWith("xxxNameYYY", "xxx")) {
     //do this
} else {
     //do that
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) function instead:

```
if (strncmp("xxxNameYYY", "xxx", 3)==0){
     //do this
} else {
     //do that
}
```

I your code you compare 2 pointers, not the strings they point to